# How to copy a website completely offline?

Tags: websites

I have tried WebHTTrack Website Copier . It doesn't work accurately. Is there an alternate way to do it? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "_It doesn't work_" ? It should work, if set up correctly. Note that many websites don't like being copied / scraped in this way, and have some sort of [bot / scraper protection](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34828465/4428462).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Simplest way to do it is to open a Terminal window and type:

```
wget -mkEpnp http://example.org
```

or a detailed version

```
wget --mirror --convert-links --adjust-extension --page-requisites 
--no-parent http://example.org
```

You can find more details here: [Make Offline Mirror of a Site using `wget` | guyrutenberg.com](https://www.guyrutenberg.com/2014/05/02/make-offline-mirror-of-a-site-using-wget/)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: This is the most simple way i found it yet.
" wget -m -k -K -E http://url/of/web/site "

Comment: It will process incorrectly paths like test.css?123